# Rails 3 : prototype to jquery question

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

How do I switch these create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb files from prototype to jquery?

### create.js.erb

```
$("follow_form").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("followers").update('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

### destroy.js.erb

```
$("follow_form").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("followers").update('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

This is the only prototype stuff I have in my app and I want to switch over to jquery and start to learn from there. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely similar

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')
```

1. Change the selector to have a # in front of the id
2. use the [jquery .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function instead of `update`

Comment: Make sure you test .html() in safari, I had some very strange results last week and had to use replaceWith() instead