# Problem with customising the follow functionality from chapter 12 of railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement the follow functionality from chapter 12 of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial but i'm new to Rails and i fear i've bitten off more than i can chew.

My app uses devise and contains Posts, Responses and Comments rather than the microposts from the earlier chapters of the tutorial. I'd like to be able to see the posts, responses and comments of users when they are followed.

As it now stands, with the simple hacks i've done, the views are all in order and the app is not throwing up any visible errors.

The follow button is not working though and I'm getting the following error in the terminal:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `authenticate' for #<RelationshipsController:0x000001049ee238>):
```

What modifications should i do to the code provided in chapter 12 in order to get it working with my app? Any help would be most appreciated!

Edit:

Here is the code of my relationship controller:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of your RelationshipsController?

Comment: Cheers @JCorcuera - I've edited my original question to include the code.

Comment: I've changed ':authenticate' to ':authenticate_user!' and adding followers now seems to be somewhat working though i'm not getting any feedback from the app such as 'now following user'. If i click on 'follow' the button does not change to 'unfollow' unless i leave the page and return.

Comment: The change from :authenticate to :authenticate_user! is correct. About the follow action, are you doing with html or js?

Comment: @JCorcuera With js. I've disabled Prototype and am only using Jquery. Could that be the problem? Thanks so much for your assistance thus far, by the way!

Comment: @Jorcuera, I've changed the create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb files to a jquery friendly syntax as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005895/rails-3-prototype-to-jquery-question. Thanks once again for pointing me in the right direction. Any idea how i might change the code referring to microposts so that it refers to posts, responses and comments?

Comment: @Ribena i suggest to close this question and start another with your problem about micropost and post, don't forget to paste the code to see where is the problem. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question. Thanks to JCorcuera for twice pointing me in the right direction. Aside from changing :authenticate to :authenticate_user! i also had to change the create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb files to a jquery friendly syntax as per this answer: [Rails 3 : prototype to jquery question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005895/rails-3-prototype-to-jquery-question).